# Mapping columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables in SQL

"Table A"

```
A1   A2     
1    Actual      
2    Forecast
```

"Table B"

```
B1  B2  A1
109 89  1 
109 98  1
```

I want to write a query that pulls columns from Table B with an extra columns that maps appropriate data from Table A. See example below.

Result

```
B1  B2  A1 A2
109 89  1  Actual
109 98  1  Actual
```

Comment: This is a very basic `INNER JOIN`.  You should research that - there are plenty of existing online tutorials to help guide you.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure where to start, I'll manage from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siyual is right that this is a very basic inner join.

```
select b.B1, b.B2, a.A1, a.A2
  from TableA a
 inner join TableB b
    on a.a1 = b.a1
```